# Package an angular app independant of deploy location?

Tags: angular

Is there a way to package an angular application which can be deployed in different location such as

- https://my-server/
- https://my-server/my-app/

I know you have to change base href parameter but it requires rebuilding the application. Is there a recommanded way to build once and deploy anywhere?

Comment: You do not really need to do a rebuild. Changing the `href` value of the `<base>` tag in `index.html` should be enough.